# Discard message after specif time from blockingqueue

Tags: java, queue

I am adding message into BlockingQueue.Validity of all type of message shouldbe 2 Seconds.All the message should be discarded after 2 seconds.Is there any way to automatic remove the message from Queue after 2 Seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Most queue strategies simply invalid/ignore entries which have been cancelled or expired.  When you consume a message, you can check whether it has expired and discard it if it has.

Comment: so shall i take time in the message.

Comment: You will have to store it somewhere.  If you don't want to add it to the message, you could write the message in a class which holds the time as well.